# How to use math jax?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, mathjax

I've been read the docs and I still don't get how to apply it from TeX

so basically i wanted to convert this string

`<p><span class='math-tex'>\\( x&gt;0,y&gt;0 \\)</span></p>`

`<p><span class='math-tex'>( (\\frac{2}{7},\\frac{2}{18}) )</span></p>`

they are tex version right ? using `\\( \\)`

from my API and I still have no idea how to convert it

```
    <script>
       MathJax = {
        tex: {
        inlineMath: [['$', '$'], ['\\(', '\\)']],
        }
         };
      </script>

    <script type='text/javascript' async
        src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'>

    </script>
    <p>
     <span class='math-tex'>( (\\frac{2}{7},\\frac{2}{18}) )</span> 
    </p>
```

I also have been inspect the example and even the [live demo](https://www.mathjax.org/#demo)

`When $a \ne 0$, there are two solutions to \(\\frac{2}{7}\) and they are
$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$`

and i still have no idea how to convert this tex `$$x = {-b \pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac} \over 2a}.$$`

Comment: you shouldn't use \\ instead use single \

Answer (score 1):

You are using `\\` instead you should use `\`.

Here is your working code.

```html
<script>
  MathJax = {
    tex: {
      inlineMath: [
        ['$', '$'],
        ['\\(', '\\)']
      ],
    }
  };
</script>

<script type='text/javascript' async src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.5/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_CHTML'>
</script>
<p>
  <span class='math-tex'>( \(\frac{2}{7},\frac{2}{18}\) )</span>
</p>
```

Comment: well the strings i got always include double slash so i couldnt modify em `\\(` even if i replace \\( with `$` it still doesnt work... but i figured out by wrapping the innerHTML with '$$' will always work for everything.