# How to modify value inside HTML tags by class name

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

I've been given this string `<p><span class='math-tex'>\\( x&gt;0,y&gt;0 \\)</span></p>`

And I want to modify the inside value, so it would render with math jax

To be come like this
 `<p><span class='math-tex'>$$\\( x&gt;0,y&gt;0 \\)$$</span></p>`

There are `$$` wrapping the value.

I am clueless how to use math jax properly, I think this is the best way to solve from my previous thread -> ([How to use math jax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58172412/how-to-use-math-jax))

But I have no idea how modify the those value when the window load on start

Comment: did my answer help u?

Comment: @helle nope... i forgot but it's not detecting but thanks for the reply, and somehow i already solve by another method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pure javascript for that. See the links for further reading.

```
<script>
  window.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
    let elementsArray = document.getElementsByClassName("math-tex");
    elementsArray[0].setAttribute("class", "some-other-class-name");
    elementsArray[0].innerHtml("some other value");
  });
</script>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute